# Poisson equation with Hardy space in 2D

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis

If $f\in\mathcal{H}^{1}$, then the problem

\begin{equation}
\Delta u=f\quad\text{in}\ \mathbb{R}^{2},\quad\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}u(x)=0,
\end{equation}

admits the unique solution
\begin{equation}
u(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}f(y)\log|x-y|\rm{d}y\in D^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^{2})\cap D^{2,1}(\mathbb{R}^{2}).
\end{equation}

How to prove this proposition?